# zero-sets of $\beta X$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to understand the following proof from Walker:

**Proposition.** The zero-sets of $\beta X$ are countable intersections of closures in $\beta X$ of zero-sets of $X$.

*Proof.* If $Z$ is a zero set of $\beta X$, then it's the zero of some function $\beta f$ with $f \in C^*(X)$, $Z(\beta f)$. Thus: $$Z(\beta f)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{p \in \beta X: |\beta f(p)|\leq 1/n\}$$

But then we can write that:

$$Z(\beta f)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty cl_{\beta X}\{x \in  X: |f(x)|\leq 1/n\}$$

Which completes the proof.

**Question**:
I'm not seeing why does the first equation imples the second. I think that I must show that for each $n$ the equality $\{p \in \beta X: |\beta f(p)|\leq 1/n\}=cl_{\beta X}\{x \in  X: |f(x)|\leq 1/n\}$ holds. $\supset$ is easy, but I'm having trouble with the other inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the other inclusion does not necessarily hold. Consider e.g. for fixed $n$ the function $f_n\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then $\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant 1/n\} = \varnothing$, but $\{ p \in \beta\mathbb{R} : \lvert\beta f_n(p)\rvert \leqslant 1/n\} \neq \varnothing$.

However, since we take the intersection over all $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, it comes out correctly, since

$$\{ p \in \beta X : \lvert \beta f(p)\rvert \leqslant 1/n\} \subset \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} \{ x\in X : \lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant 1/(n-1)\}$$

for $n > 1$.

Thus we take an intersection of two interleaved nested (decreasing) sequences of sets, and then the intersections are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking about the converse: Is every countable intersection of closure of zero sets of $X$ an zero set of $\beta X$?

Comment: In any space, the countable intersection of zero sets is a zero set. So it boils down to the question whether the closure of an $X$-zero set is a $\beta X$-zero set. I suspect it is so, but since the Stone-Čech compactification can be rather complicated, I don't know for sure. I don't see how one could construct a counterexample, but I haven't found a proof yet either.